# How to change a stylebook's style resource properties from a TStyleBook object runtime

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I want to be able to change style resources from a given stylebook object on FMX.
I know that I can change a specific object style by using the following commands

```
r1 := aButton.FindStyleResource('backgroundRect') as TRectangle ;
if Assigned(r1) then
   r1.Fill.Color := TAlphaColor(col);
```

However I need this to change for **all the objects that have this style resource** and not that specific "aButton".

How am I able to do it, so that I won't be forced to achieve this by looping through all the objects that i want to be changed?

Comment: Which Delphi version do you use, and which style are you looking at?

Comment: I am using Tokyo and have made custom styles for my components. However I want them to change runtime by the user selecting properties and this change to be made to all the objects with this specific stylename